# Custom Properties Using Sitecore Active Directory Module

Tags: sitecore

Trying to setup custom properties using the Sitecore AD Module. Have done the steps provided in Chapter 3 of the [Ad Module - Admin Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/Downloads/Active_Directory/1_0/Active_Directory_1_2/Non-secure/sitecore-active-directory-module-guide-sc72-80-a4.ashx), but keep getting stuck with the error below. Wondering if anyone has successfully set this up with Sitecore 8?

Error: Provider name cannot be null or empty when adding the line below to the web config.

add name="ad" type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="portalConn" 
applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" connectionUsername="UserName" 
connectionPassword="***" connectionProtection="Secure" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true"

Connection String:
add name="portalConn" connectionString="LDAP://ADServer/OU=Portal,DC=Dev,DC=Com"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and the suggestions from this post helped me fix it:
http://techitpro.com/active-directory-module-sitecore/

ERROR: Provider name cannot be null or empty.

The yellow screen of death appears in case you have not mentioned Full Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) in the connectionstrings.config file for your LDAP location. Ensure that LDAP connectionstring contains FQDN with port as well.

You might face same error in case if you are not using correct username and password to access your domain. So check the username and password supplied in the provider setting are correct, not locked out or not expired.